# Rails Koala gem and friends count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala

Can somebody help me with getting total_count of user friends?

```
u.facebook.get_connection("me", "friends",api_version:"v2.0")
```

This return 0 because it return friends that also use my app.

But in api 2.0 facebook give total_count field with friends number

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 455
  }
}
```

How can I get this by koala gem?

```
u.facebook.get_connection("me", "friends/#{summary}",api_version:"v2.0")
```

This return error.

**ANSWER** if someone will search for this:

```
facebook.get_connection("me", "friends",api_version:"v2.0").raw_response["summary"]["total_count"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of others, you can accept this:

```
facebook.get_connection("me", "friends",api_version:"v2.0").raw_response["summary"]["total_count"]
```